# Bootstrap modal closes when it gets clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the following snippet from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine but when I click anywhere on the modal window it closes. What can be the reason for this and how can I prevent it from happening?

I'm using Angular JS with Bootstrap Lumen, bootstrap.js and ui-bootstrap.js.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by replacing the modal specific css code in the Bootstrap Lumen file with the same part from a regular Bootstrap file. I've wasted enough time on this problem so I leave tracing the exact cause to someone else.